# Is it possible to GET unfollow count per day from instagram graph API?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, instagram, instagram-api, instagram-graph-api, facebook-insights

I am trying to get follow and unfollow count per day from instagram Graph API.

Tried the metric follows_and_unfollows. It is giving me the following error:

Query used:

```
accnt_id?fields=insights.metric(follows_and_unfollows).period(day).since(2022-07-08).until(2022-08-01)
```

Response:

```
 {
 "message": "(#100) The following metrics (follows_and_unfollows) should be specified with parameter metric_type=total_value",
    "type": "OAuthException",
    "code": 100
..........
}
```

**And on trying with the method mentioned in the above error**

Query:

```
accnt_id?fields=insights.metric(follows_and_unfollows).period(day).since(2022-07-08).until(2022-08-01).metric_type(total_value)
```

Response

```
{
  "error": {
    "message": "(#100) Param metric_type on field insights: This param is not valid",
    "type": "OAuthException",
    "code": 100,
    "fbtrace_id": ""
  }
}
```

Comment: And - did you try to do what the error message said?

Comment: Yes I did. I've updated the description. It responds with invalid params exception

Comment: Hi! Did you manage to get the right api call? I'm struggling too and Facebook hasn't documented it yet

Comment: Nope could not find an API. One way would be to fetch the real-time `followers count` and `new followers count`data and store them each day. 
Unfollow count can be found by subtracting net followers growth from new followers count.

Answer (score 0):

The link would look like how? with this specification

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I've updated the question body with the full query used